# Call d3.js zoom behaviour on jquery.UI slide event

Tags: jquery-ui, d3.js

I have a zoomable SVG area with a few objects that is responding as intended to d3.js' zoom behaviors (ie, mousewheel). Now I'm trying to attach a jQueryUI slider to my app in order to follow those behaviours.

For instance, should a `mousewheel` zoom event occur, the `slider` should move accordingly. On the other hand, `zoom` should occur if the `slider` is changed.

Right now I'm kinda lost because the widgets' slide event obviously doesn't have d3's zoom behavior's `translate` and `scale` parameters to pass on.

I've seen an example with a HTML5 slider ([here](http://bl.ocks.org/bollwyvl/871b7c781b92fd0044f5)) that is similar to what I need, but I can't get [my version](http://jsbin.com/boxozodada/edit?js,output) to work with it.

Any leads/ideas?

**:) BONUS POINTS >>>**

- I also need to hide/clip the points (they're really just text) beyond the circle's border.
- Anyway I can get the zoom to move the points to their place (as its doing right now), but **not** scale them?
- Also, what would I have to change in order to have this fully zoomed in at the start?

**EDIT:**

So, I've managed the toughest part (check [here](http://jsbin.com/lihetevone/edit?js,output)), but now I'm still trying to get the text to not scale and to clip the text beyond the circle's border. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right now I'm kinda lost because the widgets' slide event obviously
>   doesn't have d3's zoom behavior's translate and scale parameters to
>   pass on.

For this specific problem, when you zoom with the slider, you should use the slider value as `scale`, and could give to `translate` the coordinates of the center of your svg canvas.

`d3.event.translate` in the [zoom event](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#on) is simply the coordinates around where the zoom is done.

> Also, what would I have to change in order to have this fully zoomed
>   in at the start?

Just set at page start `scale` to the maximum zoom value. And `translate` to the center of your items for instance.

EDIT:

> I also need to hide/clip the points (they're really just text) beyond
>   the circle's border.

I see you are already using a [clipPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath), but it's not working. It is because you are also applying a transform to the `<g>` element, that affects the clip-path.

The easiest solution is to create a top `<g>` element just for the clipPath, then connect the `<g>` containing your items to the top.

Corrected code:

```
var topg = svg.append("g")
              .attr("clip-path","url(#clip)");

var clip = topg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
               .attr("id", "clip")
               .append("svg:circle")
               //.attr("id", "clip-circ")// You had a typo here
               .attr("cx", centerx)
               .attr("cy", centery)
               .attr("r", 149);


var pointsGroup = topg.append("g")
                  .attr("id", "pointsGroup")
                  //.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");// no longer needed here
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that fact about the translate coords. Thought it referred some projection/translation of the referential. Any thoughts on the bonus points? :)

Comment: Sure, no problem ;) I answered for the "clipping" part of your problem as well

Comment: Thanks! I had already figured it out in my local version, but I found out the same about the clipping process. Just need to fix the text scaling, but that is proving quite the challenge. Again, thank you!

Comment: For the text, a straightforward solution would be to do ```selectAll("svg:text").attr("transform","scale("+ 1/d3.event.scale +")")``` in the zoom event callback. I'm glad you solved your other problems, cheers

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that simple. Using your suggestion breaks the previous translation and the clipping process as well: http://jsbin.com/sudimahaxa/edit?js,output